# Ruby regex not ignoring whitespace

Tags: ruby, regex

Matching S01E01 in Ruby

with

```
/S\d+?E\d+?/ix
```

which works, however, S01 E01 does not. I thought the /x should ignore white spaces?

Answer (score 10):

/x ignores whitespace inside your regex, not in the text you're matching.

You're looking for

```
/S\d+?\s*E\d+?/i
```

Answer (score 3):

The `x` option ignores whitespace **in the regex itself**, which allows you to better format your regexes for reading without modifying their meaning. You could write:

```
irb(main):008:0> r = /
irb(main):009:0/ S
irb(main):010:0/ d+?
irb(main):011:0/ E
irb(main):012:0/ d+?
irb(main):013:0/ /ix
```

To get an regex with the same meaning as your example.